# What is making /tmp/info-html*.tmp files and how do I stop it?

Tags: linux, shell, tmp

What is making /tmp/info-html*.tmp files and how do I stop it or configure it to clean these up and/or make these somewhere else?

For example,

```
# ll /tmp/info-html*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Oct 30  2014 /tmp/info-html.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Oct 30  2014 /tmp/info-html1.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Oct 30  2014 /tmp/info-html2.tmp
...
```

These accumulate very quickly and are always empty when I see them.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of cleaning up after the fact, you should probably monitor the spot with `lsof` to determine what is writing the files and figure out how to stop it:

```
lsof +d /tmp/ -r 1 | grep "info-html"
```

Alternatively, you could set up some form of auditing on that directory, but it may get really chatty.

Comment: Thanks, lsof is interesting and I've never used it before. Unfortunately it only tells me the user and I think it's coming from apache so there's a lot of web stuff that could be creating these files.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with reduxframework which may be a WordPress plugin, or included by a WordPress theme. To find it try something like that:

```
grep -rniIlF 'info-html' wp-content/
```

This will give you the file and line number where you should find something like:

```
$sampleHTML = $wp_filesystem->get_contents( dirname( FILE ) . '/info-html.html' );
```

Replace it with:

```
$sampleHTML = file_get_contents( dirname( FILE ) . '/info-html.html' );
```

Also, see a long discussion about that: https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/issues/1383

Answer (score -1):

Could be at least

- Some web application such as `WordPress` doing that under some circumstances.
- A regularly ran cronjob, see `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.*` and `crontab -l -u user`, where `user` is the user who owns those files.
- Some daemon which periodically creates those tiles, failing to remove them because of a bug, interrupted operation or some other reason.

Hard to tell, your question lacks lots of details.

Comment: Thanks. I'm almost sure it's php/wordpress but I don't have any great way to nail it down exactly.